# Yii move rules out of a (very) fat model

Tags: activerecord, yii

In a large application, one of the main models is `Venue` which has already around 50 rules, that are spanning over 80 lines. The model itself have started growing to over 1000 lines of code, so I started decomposing it.

First I started moving out some value objects. I was thinking if it would be appropriate to move out the rules into separate dummy class, something like:

```
class Venue {
...

    public function rules() {
        return VenueRules::getRules();
    }

...
}
```

Is there a better approach on managing the rules in the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the preferable way to do it. You can also extend the model with a class which holds the bigger methods. We like to use services to slim our models down and place the business logic apart from it.